# Extract any value from hashmap (one for each key)

Tags: java, java-8

I have a large map with different keys and several values (DepthFeed) associated to each. I would like to get any value (DepthFeed) from that to be able to extract the name of the instrument one for each key.

I have this map

```
private static Map<Integer, List<DepthFeed>> mapDepthFeed = new HashMap<>();
```

From that I would like to do something like, however not returning the keyset integer. Instead I want a `List<DepthFeed>` back (containing one row for each key)

```
List<DepthFeed> d = mapPriceFeed.values().stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `I have a large map with non unique keys.`. How is that possible since a `Map`key is unique by definition.

Comment: Bad wording by me, I mean I have a map with many keys and many rows for each key

Comment: It’s more than bad wording as you are calling `distinct()` on a `keySet().stream()` which shows that you didn’t understand that keys are already distinct.

Comment: And please, don’t use the word “rows” as there are no rows in your code. Don’t expect us to guess what the term “rows” maps to in the collection code. Saying what kind of result type you expect might help.

Comment: @Holger, luckily for the OP such `distinct()` operation will be optimized out.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: the problem is not the performance but the lack of understanding which the code exhibits. Keep in mind that code is also a kind of documentation.

Comment: @Holger read that I am saying I want something like distinct on the values. And asking her is because of lack of understanding otherwise I wouldn't be her reading comments on how stupid I am.'

Comment: @user2130951: no, your last comment is the first time that you are saying  that you want to get distinct values. Look at your question. You are not telling it anywhere. You are talking about keys there. And what do you mean with “something like”? Do you want distinct values or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
List<DepthFeed> result = mapDepthFeed.values().stream()
            .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
            .map(list -> list.get(0))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This way you will get the first element from each non-empty list stored in map values.